# Eventbus - how to unregister POJO?

Tags: android, android-event, greenrobot-eventbus

How and where should I unregister the EventBus in POJO which is independent from the android lifecycle? (no onCreate-, no onDestroy-method)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [this might be usefull](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/99)

Answer (score 1):

> How and where should I unregister the EventBus in POJO

How: by calling `unregister()` on the `EventBus`

Where: in your Java code

When: at the point when you no longer want the object to be receiving events

Since nobody but you knows what this POJO is, what it does, why it *is* a POJO versus an Android component, etc., nobody can tell you more specifically when to call `unregister()`.

Comment: Question how to unregister() in POJO its plain java class we can register in a constructor of class but where to unregister because we don't have onDestory method in java class.

Comment: @RahulDevanavar: Something that is lifecycle-aware could tell the POJO to unregister.

Comment: for plain java don't  have any such question.

Comment: @RahulDevanavar: greenrobot's EventBus is an Android library, not a plain Java library. Most entry points in Android (activity, service, receiver, provider) have a lifecycle, though in the case of the receiver often the "lifecycle" is a single `onReceive()` method. Hence, most of the time, something with a lifecycle is responsible for the POJO. Regardless, you are the one who decided to use a POJO with a bus, and you need to determine what the trigger is for having that POJO register and unregister (or, alternatively, let it stay registered until process termination).